# Azure - Adding the contents of an email to sql azure db table

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-logic-apps

I'm very new to Azure and want to achieve something quite basic. I want my logic app to trigger once a new email is received and then store the subject in my sql Azure database table.

I think there are more steps involved than what I have done at the moment but currently I'm getting a 400 error once a new email is received.

My logic app:

[image]

My error when a new email is received:

[image]

```
{
  "odata.error": {
    "code": "InvalidInput",
    "message": {
      "lang": "en-US",
      "value": "An error occurred while processing this request.\nRequestId:f4a9fb02-d002-0035-399f-de277b000000\nTime:2020-12-30T11:32:05.9797960Z"
    }
```

I've created a new table called Emails and inside I have specified a column called subject with datatype nvarchar(250). I don't think I have specified which column to add the subject into so I believe that is the cause of the error.

Does anyone know how to solve this and point me in the right direction? Apologies for the basic nature of this question too. Thanks

Comment: I think you're using Azure Storage Tables, not Azure SQL.

Comment: ah that would make sense. So only option I see that looks like that is the Azure SQL data warehouse, is that the one I'm after if I've created a normal sql azure db?

Comment: _Azure SQL Data Warehouse_ is a different SKU of Azure SQL, but as I said, it looks like you aren't using Azure SQL at all.

Comment: _Azure Table Storage_ (aka _Azure Storage Tables_) is **completely unrelated** to Azure SQL and Azure SQL Data Warehouse. Your data exists in a Storage Account that you will see in Azure Portal and/or Azure Storage Explorer.

Comment: Okay thanks for your response. I'm still a bit confused though - I've created a new Azure Sql DB in my resource group as that is what i want to use. Then, in my logic app, what is the operation that I want? Again apologies if this is basic

Comment: " Then, in my logic app, what is the operation that I want?" - follow this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-sqlazure

Comment: Thanks mate :) much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Like @Dai said, you are not using Azure SQL database.

You can add a SQL Server action: Insert row or Execute stored procedure to insert the email object into Azure SQL database.

The workflow should like this:
[image]

Ref the tutorial: [Automate workflows for a SQL database by using Azure Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-sqlazure#add-a-sql-action)

Note: please the set the [Azure SQL database firewall](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/firewall-create-server-level-portal-quickstart) "Allow Azure services and resources to access this server": **On**

HTH.